# APPIUM is with server error but nothing is solving

Tags: testing, automated-tests, appium, webdriver-io

Hello guys anyone knows about Appium ? I’m getting much errors on server side, and nothing is working, I restarted and searched for several times how to solve, but nothing is working..
I'm using Appium 1.22.3 and I just open the appium desktop and when needed I verify the appium-doctor but there is no issues with any configuration there.
[500 server error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iTgS.png)
[failed because of server error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stBtc.png)

I need to solve this problem to use the appium to write tests, I'm using webdriver.io